# Convert BinaryFormatter into Protobuf.net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net, .net-6.0, binaryformatter

With MS removing support for BinaryFormatter in .net 6 and completely removing in .net 8 we have decided to change to Protobuf-net.

Our current use case is that when users save their project data it uses the BinaryFormatter to serialise all project data to disk for later retrieval.

My question is has anyone had success in converting users already serialized data (BinaryFormatter) into Protobuf-net

I am looking to see if there are recommendations/patterns on how to automatically uplift the serialized data into the new format.

Initially I am thinking a separate console application that dynamically loads the old assemblies, deserializes the project data into memory objects and then swap out the old assemblies for the updated protobuf-net version and serialize back to disk.

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: _"My question is has anyone had success in converting users already serialized data (BinaryFormatter) into Protobuf-net"_ - you can easily test that yourself by making a **pre**-NET 6 tool to read the data written by BinaryFormatter and write it out into a new file using Protobuf

Comment: Is it not possible to just create a single net5 assembly that supports both, and use an automapping library to transfer between the two sets of classes?

Comment: _"...I am thinking a separate console application that dynamically loads the old assemblies, deserializes the project data into memory objects and then swap out the old assemblies..."_ - that requires child AppDomains and the ability to create and unload them which sadly isn't supported https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.createdomain?view=net-6.0#system-appdomain-createdomain(system-string).  Why they didn't allow it in say the established [**net6.0-windows**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks) TPL is beyond me. :(

Comment: _"...Is it not possible to just create a single net5 assembly that supports both..."_ - did you miss it when I said _"by making a pre-NET 6 tool to read the data written by BinaryFormatter and write it out into a new file using Protobuf"_.  Such a tool will be the **converter**.  I think you will need to deploy that to your users and have them run it before hand.  When users run your .NET 6, they need to import the converted file.